# Calling a template variable from an output modifier in Modx?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I'm trying to output a template variable inside the if statement in ModX, but it gives no output.

I have multiple pages with links to articles and the point is to only output template variable content on the first page but not the others.

```
// This gives no output:
[[!#get.page:is=`1`:or:is=``:then=`[[*content]]`:else=``]

// This outputs "yes" on the first page and "no" on others:
[[!#get.page:is=`1`:or:is=``:then=`yes`:else=`no`]]
```

I've even tried this, but it still does not give any output. I guess the problem is not about the output modifier:

```
[[!#get.page:is=`1`:or:is=``:then=`[[*content]]`:else=`[[*content]]`]
```

I'm using ModX Revo 2.7.0

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in your case missing a double closing angle bracket "]]"

```
[[!#get.page:is=`1`:or:is=``:then=`[[*content]]`:else=``]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `` `or:is=` `` is matching against an empty state. Unless that is intentional you should be able to remove it. Also, the ``` `:else=`` ``` is the default state, so, you don't need that either.

The following should work and you'll have cleaner code:

```
[[!#get.page:is=`1`:then=`[[*content]]`]]
```